# How do I integrate COM in Java?

Tags: java

I need to use an API written in COM with Java.
Is there a simple way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: are you talking about [Java communication API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html)?

Comment: @Harry, the op is talking about COM, ala windows technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/), I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Google told me, there are a few different libs for that:

http://j-interop.org/

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jcom/

Or you cold write a Wrapper for the OCX in C and use that via JNI.
This would however violate the 'simple' requirement :)